# Confusion over a sign in the unit circle

Tags: trigonometry

On the unit circle, if we have an angle $\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\pi$, we can write $\theta = \pi-\phi$, where $\phi < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Say we then take $$\cos(\theta)=\cos(\pi - \phi)=-\cos(\phi)$$
This would give a positive value, because of the restriction on $\phi$, but for $\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta <\pi$, the graph of cosine is negative.

I am not sure where I have made a mistake.

Comment: $\cos\phi$ would be positive

Answer (score 1):

If $\dfrac\pi2<\theta<\pi$ and $\phi=\pi-\theta$, then $0<\phi\lt \dfrac\pi2$, so $\cos\phi$ is positive, so $\cos\theta=-\cos\phi$ is negative.